# Keras backend way to create tensor of mean values the same length as original tensor?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

If i have a tensor 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. Is there something i can use in the backend to make a tensor [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]?

I am trying to compute a baseline loss based on the average value for the output

```
avg_true = K.mean(y_true)
baseline = sigmoid_loss(avg_true, y_pred)
```

I'm not sure if the code here (avg_true, y_pred) is working because avg_true is just a single value and y_pred is a tensor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need something like this:

```
X = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
avg_true = tf.fill(tf.shape(X), tf.reduce_mean(X))
# [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```